# RemoteApp and encrypted connection strings in the machine.config

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop-services

We have several applications which use encrypted connection strings from with the machine.config on the server.

Now we are starting to experiment with RemoteApps, but are getting the error:

[image]

Whenever a non-Adminstrator user attempts to connect to the app.

**How do I get a normal domain user to be able to access the encrypted connection strings in the server's machine.config via a RemoteApp?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually was able to find that I needed to allow the user access to the  RSAProviderName in order to decrypt the connectionStrings block. The answer came from this [Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mosharaf/2005/11/17/encrypting-configuration-files-using-protected-configuration/)

> ```
> “Failed to decrypt using provider ‘RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider’.
>  Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened
> ```
>
> Fortunately the ASPNet_regiis tool gives us the option to add users to the ACL of the key containers using the –pa parameter.
>
> For example to give access to the ASPNET user
>
> ```
> aspnet_regiis -pa “<key container name>” “ASPNET”
> ```

The `<key container name>` can be found in the machine.config under the `<configProtectedData>` under the property `keyContainerName`